# Save Image-Path into SQL, Webmatrix

Tags: sql, string, image, webmatrix

I want to create a group-function to my Website. In every group there should be a group-image, which people can upload. So I must save the path into my SQL-DB. My Code:

```
newFileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "_" + Path.GetFileName(photo.FileName);
imagePath = @"images\" + newFileName;
imageThumbPath = @"images\thumbs\" + newFileName;
var setPath = (@"~\"  + imageThumbPath);
var intoGroupImg = ("UPDATE groups SET img= " + @setPath+ " WHERE id= "+@grID);
db.Execute(intoGroupImg);
```

I always get the error-message: Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 26,Token in error = images. I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

I've got a solution:

```
var intoGroupImg = ("UPDATE groups SET img = @0 WHERE id= " +@grID);
db.Execute(intoGroupImg, imageThumbPath);
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, please, please use parameterized queries. It is your smoking gun versus SQL injection. Even if you're not adding user-input, it is a good habit to get into.

Anyway, I'm not sure what some of your `@` symbols are in there for, but I am used to using C#.net with WebMatrix, but I *think* that is what you're using also. Try this:

```
var newFileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "_" + Path.GetFileName(photo.FileName);

var imagePath = "images/" + newFileName;
var imageThumbPath = "images/thumbs/" + newFileName;
var setPath = "~/" + imageThumbPath;
var intoGroupImg = "UPDATE groups SET img = @0 WHERE id = @1";

db.Execute(intoGroupImg, setPath, grID);
```

This is how I would imagine it to look in C# with parameterized queries.

Given the line offset I believe the error is from `@setPath` but I'm not sure. Try going to the database tab in WebMatrix and manually doing a query with what you expect the value of `@setPath` to be.

Also, I noticed you used "backslashes" instead of "forward slashes" in the concatenated string in your example. Is this intentional? Is that what the `@` symbol is doing? Keeping you from having to escape each backslash with `\\`? Either way, the forward slash `/` in its place should do fine, no?

Anyway, hope I helped, at least some.